# Firewall Rules on azure

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, database-administration

Can we create a rule that prevents someone adding a DB Firewall Rule with the name ClientIPAddress*** ??

Thanks in advance,

Comment: add a role to prevent adding client IP address, it's not possible.

Comment: Hi @Surya,If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Surya, do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL database use the [firewall rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-create-server-level-portal-quickstart) to control the access. For example, create a firewall rule to allow the access from the client through IP address.

To be able to [create and manage IP firewall rules for the Azure SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure#permissions), you will need to either be:

- in the SQL Server Contributor role
- in the SQL Security Manager role
- the owner of the resource that contains the Azure SQL Server

We can't create a rule that prevents someone adding a DB Firewall Rule with the name ClientIPAddress***. But if someone is not in these roles, they don't have the permission to add role with client IP.